# Chart Controls: Stacked Column Series Label Positioning

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-chart-controls

I am creating a stacked column graph but am currently limited by the lack of label positioning for each series. There are not any custom properties which relate to alignment of label positioning, is there some other way to offset labels or align them for stacked charts?

Comment: Aren't the labels displayed within the columns ? What do you mean by offset, can you expand a bit more on that ?

Comment: Basically, I would like to be able to position the labels outside of their default position, like having a label appear to the right of the  column. By offset, I mean being able to supply a manual value for alignment, such as specifying that all labels should appear ten pixels above where they should be.

Comment: Did you try with Custom properties of the series `LabelStyle=Right` ?

Comment: Yes. This has no effect with the stacked column type of graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By creating a dummy series and manually setting each label value you can reposition a stacked columns labels to either the top or bottom of the stack.  It is limited, and certainly not what I would like, but it is the best I have found so far.

While the control used is different the best example of the concept I have found is here:
[total value of each column in a stacked column](http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1106)

Check out my blog post for more details and a better method of handling this:
http://jeremeguenther.blogspot.com/2015/02/overlapping-columns-in-microsoft-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

last paragraph from the msdn : [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156263%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

you might wanna check out the `SmartLabelStyle` altough I've never used it with column chart type. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.smartlabelstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)